# How many numbers from $0$ to $1000000$ contain exactly two $3$'s and two $5$'s and two $6$'s?

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers from $0$ to $1000000$ contain exactly two $3$'s and two $5$'s and two $6$'s?

Comment: $90$. What have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: 3*3*9^4 number of numbers containing two 3

Comment: $\frac{(2+2+2)!}{2!\times2!\times2!}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions asks for two $3$'s, two $5$'s and two $6$'s. Thus we must at least have 6-digits. As the number must be less than 1000000, it must have at most 6-digits. From these two we can conclude that it must have exactly 6-digits.
Thus the answer is:$(^6_2)(^4_2)(^2_2)=\frac{6!}{(2!)^3}=90$. Done!

Comment: how do we get exactly 6! And 2!^3? And what if we change range from 0 to 100 000 000

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov. well there are a total of six positions, of which I have to choose two positions to place a '$3$'. that can be done in $(^6_2)$ ways. Of the remaining four places I have to choose two more for the '$5$'. and that can be done in $(^4_2)$ ways and the '$6$' can be put in $(^2_2)$ ways. Now, we know that these three quantities will be multiplied. Therefore the answer will be $(^6_2)(^4_2)(^2_2)=\frac{6!}{4!.2!}.\frac{4!}{2!.2!}.\frac{2!}{2!.0!}=\frac{6!}(2!)^3=90$.

Comment: Nice thinking!!